# Error: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have downloaded one android studio app from internet when i open this i got errors like below image 
how can i resolve this please help me

```
[![apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.lcp.lcptransportation"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 22
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
        compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    }][1]][1]
```

### i installed below versions:-

[image]

Comment: i installed but still showing

Answer (score 0):

This is the error of build tool hear you set build tool 22 but i think it not be installed in your SDK so first go in you SDK manager and install build tool other wise click on link after error.
It may be solve your problem.